# finding sum of values from a single column in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a column in crystal reports named flag. it has values of both 0's and 1's. what is the best way to find out the sum of all the zeroes and sum of all the ones separately  from a single column.

Also I need to find the number of values in a particular column.(here zeroes and ones)?

Comment: Havent you posted the same question twice.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920084/counting-0s-and-1s-from-a-single-column-in-crystal-reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get this by having two Formula fields,

1. formulafield1
   Here you will write the logic like if flagfield is zero then 1 else 0.
   Sample syntax

> IF {Table.flag} = 0
>       THEN 1 ELSE 0;

2. Formulafield2
    you will write the opposite condition here if flagfield is 1 then 1 else 0.
   (in your example you can use directly flag value it self)

now

> sum(formulafield1)

will give number of zeros 
and

> sum(Formulafield2)

will give number of ones

Please note i have used crystal reports long back .. please check syntax once .. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. :) It worked. the syntax is sum({@....}).what if we need to count the no of values in a given column>